# WHat would be the definition of "The Pengest Munch"?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english, learning

although I know the word peng and pengest I can't fifure out the meaning by the joint of words pengest and munch

Comment: Did you do any research?

Answer (score 4):

'Peng' is very *very* informal 'street' London teen slang and London Multicultural English (LME) for good, nice, pleasant, attractive (etc). Even many UK people will not know what it means, especially if they are over about 20 years of age.

'-est' is an ending for some adjectives when the meaning is 'the most *adjective*', thus smallest, biggest, hottest, nicest, fastest, etc. Sometimes the final consonant is doubled so big/biggest, hot/hottest.

'Munch' is an informal verb meaning 'chew' (of food).

So a first guess might be 'the most pleasant food'.

This is confirmed by a quick (very quick) Google search, showing that 'the Pengest Munch' is the name of a series of Youtube videos where London area fried-chicken outlets are reviewed.

My grandson says that 'peng' has been outdated since about 2017, and (his words) "only lamers say 'peng'".

[image]

Comment: I worry about the long-term health of this person.

Comment: I grew up in south London. I can't describe how sublimely odd it is to see a review of a fried-chicken joint in Carshalton.

Comment: It's a feature of LME that superlatives can be formed by adding -est to any adjective. Also 'bad' can mean 'good', so I wouldn't be surprised to see 'The baddest jollof rice in Purley' from this guy.